# Flex ByteArray data field

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, arrays

The data provider (ArrayCollection) for my data grid consists of objects with ByteArray (int) fields. How do I make the data field display as int without transforming my data provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure, but in order to display something like that in datagrid i'd do this:

```
<mx:itemRenderer>
    <mx:Component>
        <mx:Label 
            text="{ ( data.yourByteArray.toString()) }" 
            textDecoration="none" <!-- other props -->
        />
    </mx:Component>
</mx:itemRenderer>
```